# Post code indented with tabs

Tags: support, code-formatting

Can I copy my code, which is indented with tabs, inside a StackOverflow question (or answer) and have it recognized as code?

Comment: I didn't downvote - but I did look for questions to close this as a duplicate of. I don't think your downvotes are due to a tabs vs. spaces disagreement, though.

Comment: @WaiHaLee This is very close to that duplicate Nicol said. I didn't find that one because I was looking specifically for the tabs indentation. But this one has a key difference, which is the tabs requirement. The answer there seems to be able to deal with any code (didn't test though), so even I marked this one as dup. I commented there the answer here, because it wasn't, so that they add it to their great answer. If someone thinks this is a dup, he should flag it, not only downvote; but downvoting only is nonsense, I think.

Answer (score -15):

For blocks of code, to preserve newlines:

Indent everything one (1) tab (ensure there is a blank line between the top/bottom of the block and other text)

Comment: Directly from the dupe: "Indent everything four (4) spaces" [...] "Code copy/pasted from an IDE is often already tabbed. When rendering, tabs are replaced with spaces."

Comment: @KevinKruse I don't want to press space for 100 times if I can press tab once. That dupe doesn't say that you can replace those 4 spaces with a tab. Those spaces are never rendered, so that is not the same

Comment: I downvoted this answer because, despite knowing exactly how the system works, this answer leaves me *more confused*. By the way, did you know you can configure your editor to insert spaces when you press the Tab key?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, but there's no way I'm going to reconfigure my editor with a wrong configuration just to copy my code to SO, and then have to reconfigure it back to the right way, and repeat every time I post something here; even if it is 1 minute.  Even more having the option of using tabs here.

Comment: Hmm, no, I wasn’t suggesting reconfiguring the editor every time. I was suggesting it as a permanent change, since code should always be indented with spaces. I also struggle to understand why you are so frequently copying and pasting code to Stack Overflow. Code in questions should be a *minimal* example, not a full dump of your project code.

Comment: @CodyGray I will use spaces the day someone pays me enough for that.  And if I write an answer (or a question) for SO, I like to prepare it well on my sane editor (gedit, which by default comes with the *right* configuration) and then I just copy and paste.